# ¿Cómo puedo imprimir ésta página en PDF?

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf

Necesito convertir esta página web en PDF pero cuando lo hago me lo renderiza mal. Solo me pasa cuando uso el pagesplit en true. Pero si no pongo en true no tengo forma de generar paginas adicionales.

```
  <?php 
include ('includes/connection.php'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Ingreso de prestadores</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-
 alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-
  rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" 
  crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/7.0.0/normalize.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700" 
rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<style>
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: 40px;
}
img {
    width: 8%;
    height: 8%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-left: 70px;
}
p {
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-bottom: -1%;
    margin-right: 1%
}
th {
background-color: #E0DFDF;
border-radius: 7px;
font-size: 10px;
text-align: center;
}
td {
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-size: 10px;
}
table {
    border-color: white;
}
tfoot {
    font-size: 10px;
    background-color: #E0DFDF;
}
</style>
<?php
session_start();
$perio = $_POST['perio'];
$sql  = "SELECT a.profesional,a.periodo,a.cuit,a.provincia,b.id,b.cuit,b.prestador,c.periodo 
FROM detalles a inner join users_entidades b INNER JOIN periodo c on 
a.cuit=b.cuit and a.periodo=c.periodo WHERE b.id=".$_SESSION['idUsuario']." 
AND a.periodo='$perio'";
//$sql .= "GROUP BY a.periodo";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
?>
<div class="container">
<div>
    <div class="container-fluid img-responsive">
<img src="images/oaicono.jpg" alt="" class="img-rounded">
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">

<h2><b>Detalle Liquidación Entidad</b></h2>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-4">
    <p>Entidad:<b><?php echo $_SESSION['prestador']; ?>.</b> </p> 
<p>Provincia: <b><?php echo $row['provincia']; ?>.</b> </p> 
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <p>Período: <b><?php echo $row['periodo']; ?></b> </p>
    <p>C.U.I.T: <b><?php echo $row['cuit']; ?></b> </p>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <p>Fecha Liq: <b><?php echo $row['periodo']."/25"; ?></b> </p>
    <p>Centro Ate: <b>Odontopraxis S.A.</b></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<br>

<h4  class="text-left"><b>Comprobantes de la entidad</b></h4>
<table class="table text-center table-sm">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Afiliado</th>
            <th>Nº Afiliado</th>
            <th>Plan</th>
            <th>Fecha Prest.</th>
            <th>Prest.</th>
            <th>Pieza</th>
            <th>Arancel</th>
            <th>Mont. Liq. Exento</th>
            <th>Mont. Liq. Gravado</th>
            <th>Mont. Liq. IVA</th>
            <th>Motivo Deb/Cred</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="text-left">
    <?php
    $prestador = $row['profesional'];
    $periodo = $perio;
    mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");
    $sql1  = "SELECT * FROM detalles WHERE profesional='$prestador' AND periodo='$periodo' ORDER BY detalles.periodo ASC";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql1);
    while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><b><?php echo $row1['paciente']; ?></b></td>
            <td><b><?php echo $row1['codigo'].$row1['vinc1']; ?></b></td>
            <td><b><?php echo $row1['plan']."-".$row1['desc_plan']; ?></b></td>
            <td><b><?php echo $row1['fecha']; ?></b></td>
            <td><b><?php echo $row1['codigo_prest']; ?></b></td>
            <td class="text-center"><b><?php echo $row1['pieza']; ?></b></td>
            <td class='text-right'><b><?php echo $row1['valor']; ?></b></td>
            <?php if ($row1['iva']=='S') {
                echo "<td class='text-right'><b>--</b></td>";
                echo "<td class='text-right'><b>".$row1['valor']."</b></td>" ;
            }else{
                echo "<td class='text-right'><b>".$row1['valor']."</b></td>";
                echo "<td class='text-right'><b>--</b></td>" ;
                } ?>
                <?php if ($row1['iva']=='S') {
                    echo "<td class='text-right'><b>".number_format($row1['valor']*(0.105),2,'.',',')."</b></td>";
                }else{
                    echo "<td class='text-right'><b>0.00</b></td>";
                    } ?>
            <td class='text-center'><b><?php echo substr($row1['causa_rech'], 0, 10); ?></b></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Total</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <?php include('calculo.php'); ?>
            <td style="background-color: white;" class="text-right"><b><?php echo number_format($row['total']-$row1['gravado'],2,'.',','); ?></b></td>
            <td style="background-color: white;" class="text-right"><b><?php echo number_format($row1['gravado'],2,'.',','); ?></b></td>
            <td style="background-color: white;" class="text-right"><b><?php echo number_format($row1['gravado']*(0.105),2,'.',','); ?></b></td>
            <td style="background-color: white;"></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
</div>
 <script
 src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
 crossorigin="anonymous">
 </script>
 <script
 src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"
 integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30="
 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-
alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-
vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.debug.js">
</script>
<script src="js/html2pdf.js"></script>
<script src="js/addhtml.js"></script>
<script src="js/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script>
var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', 'a4');
var options = {
 pagesplit: true,
};
pdf.addHTML($('html'), options, function()
{
pdf.save("Detalle_liquidacion_<?php echo $perio ?>.pdf");
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Pero qué es lo que te renderiza mal?

Comment: En el momento que imprime la pagina en el pdf se ve así. No se que es lo que lo causa.

Comment: ¿Revisaste el código interno del PDF generado? Fonts incrustados, etc....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pudiera ser que tengas que usar un CSS propio para "impresión"....

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="imprimirPDFs.css">
```

Y no sólo uno generico para todo...Los tipos a definir/usar son:

```
all     Used for all media type devices
print   Used for printers
screen  Used for computer screens, tablets, smart-phones etc.
speech  Used for screenreaders that "reads" the page out loud
```